# How to read Hex from a file?

Tags: c#

I am very new at C# and I am trying to make a app that can read and write Hex to file. I have watched some great tutorials but the end product only prints a very small amount of the hex code in the text box. This is my code

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            textEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);
        }
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(textBox1.Text));
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(4);
        Array.Reverse(buffer);
        textEditor.Text = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0).ToString("X");
        br.Dispose();
    }
```

I want it to show all the text in the file, not just the first.

Comment: Process 1 byte at a time converting it to a string representation in hexadecimal, call `.ToString("X2")` on each byte to get its hexadecimal representation.

Comment: You're only reading the first four bytes. You'll want a loop to keep reading until the end of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It'll get you through the whole file. Note the `+=` on the textEditor.Text as well, I assume that's what you want.

I'm assuming that you are reading each byte in, and converting it to a 2 digit hex char then appending it. However, if I'm misinterpreting and you want to read in multiple bytes at once, I've made it easy to read in more at a time.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        textEditor.Text = "";
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open)))
        {
            int pos = 0;
            int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;
            int numBytesToRead = 1;
            int numHexCharsPerLine = 5;
            int numCharsRead = 0;
            while (pos < length)
            {
                byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(numBytesToRead);
                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
                {
                    textEditor.Text += buffer[i].ToString("X2");
                    textEditor.Text += " "; // Will put a space between each hex character
                    if (numCharsRead % numHexCharsPerLine == 0 && numCharsRead > 0)
                    {
                        textEditor.Text += "\r\n";
                    }
                    numCharsRead++;
                }
                pos += numBytesToRead;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried typing this all in but I get some errors. I don't think Im putting it in the right spot.

Comment: Try again with this since I modified it, but then tell me what your errors are.

Comment: Sorry! Fixed them, try again :)

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly. Its now like a real hex editor. One thing though. Is it possible to space the characters from each other to form columns.

Comment: Sure! First- make sure you noticed that this all needs to go in the `if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)` block, I changed that when I added the entire method here. Check out my answer above for how to add spaces in between. Finally, please don't forget to mark my answer as the accepted answer if I've helped you :)

Comment: Hey @AStick I just added some more code. I think a space may not be quite right if this is just a textbox, so I made it so it will automatically add a new line after a set number of characters. I set the number to 5, but you can change it. If you use it, let me know if that works :)

Comment: You are great! Thank you so much. And there is just one more thing if thats ok. For some reason (probably because of the video I watched) at the top of the hex code, it prints a character or two of ASC11. I think Im explaining this right but I'm not sure. Can I stop this from doing that?

Comment: Hi, I just edited it more. I removed the two lines you had in your `if` originally and made it better in my `using` line, so you might want to change those. See if the characters still are there, though I don't think I fixed it. I'm not sure where they might be coming from, so let me know if they're still there and I can think more about it.

Comment: Its better. And by the way it isn't a text box. I don't know what I was thinking when I said that. Its like a big scrollable text box.

Comment: I think the problem may have been textEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);

Comment: Yes. it was the `textEditor.Text = File.ReadAllText(textBox1.Text);`